# Runtime polymorphism and operator overload

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, run-time-polymorphism

The problem is that in main function pointer to abstract class `list` calls `operator+` of this class. But how can I call overloaded operators from child classes (`queue` and `stack`) with pointer to parent class `list`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class list
{
public:
    list* head; 
    list* tail; 
    list* next; 
    int num;
    virtual ~list() {}
    list() { head = tail = next = NULL; num = 0; }
    virtual list operator+(int i) { return *this; };
    virtual int operator-() { return 0; };
};
class queue : public list
{
public:
    list operator+(int i);
    int operator-();
};

class stack : public list
{
public:
    list operator+(int i);
    int operator-();
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); rand();
    list* p;
    queue q_ob;
    stack s_ob;
    char ch;
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Enter something else to stop.\nStack, Queue or ULL? (S/Q): \n";
        cin >> ch;
        ch = tolower(ch);
        if (ch == 'q')
            p = &q_ob;
        else if (ch == 's')
            p = &s_ob;
        else break;
        p + (rand() % 100);
    }
    cout << "Enter T to terminate\n";
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Remove from Stack, Queue or ULL? (S/Q):";
        cin >> ch;
        ch = tolower(ch);
        if (ch == 'q')
            p = &q_ob;
        else if (ch == 's')
            p = &s_ob;
        else break;
        cout << -(*p) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

list queue::operator+(int i)
{
    list* item;
    item = new queue;
    if (!item)
    {
        cout << "Allocation error.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    item->num = i;
    // put on end of list:
    if (tail)
        tail->next = item;
    tail = item;
    item->next = NULL;
    if (!head)
        head = tail;
    return *this;
}

int queue::operator-()
{
    int i;
    list* p;
    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "List empty.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    // remove from start of list
    i = head->num;
    p = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete p;
    return i;
}

list stack::operator+(int i)
{
    list* item;
    item = new stack;
    if (!item)
    {
        cout << "Allocation error.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    item->num = i; // put on front of list
    // for stack - like operation
    if (head)
        item->next = head;
    head = item;
    if (!tail)
        tail = head;
    return *this;
}

int stack::operator-()
{
    int i;
    list* p;
    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "List empty.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    // remove from start of list:
    i = head->num;
    p = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete p;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: where do you call a method in `main` using a pointer to `list` ? I didnt find it

Comment: Well, I use operator+ with pointer to list in the end of first cycle:
 `p+(rand%100)`

Comment: Having public data members in `list` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, it would be much better to make class fields private, but i think it's not why the program doesn't work

Comment: You return by value which means the return type of overriding functions is always a `list` which could be an issue, if you did anything with the result of the addition. You may want to go with `virtual list& operator+=(int);` instead, which avoids the issue, since no new object is created. I wouldn't expect the `-` operator to just return an arbitrary value btw. You shouldn't be overloading operators just for the sake of shortening the code. Overload operators only, if they behave sufficiently similar to operations on arithmetic types or `std::string`...

Comment: `p` is a `list*` your operators are for `list` objects

Comment: One suggestion, always use the keyword `override` whenever you are overriding a virtual function from the base class. It will catch, at compile time, any mistake you made while overriding a virtual function.

Comment: Thank you all. I found a mistake, I was using 'p' instead of '*p'. Sorry for wasting your time.